# show bool if row exists or doesn't

Tags: t-sql

I have the table [Contracts] with columns [id], [number]. And I also have some numbers in the string format: '12342', '23252', '1256532'. I want to get the output something like this.

```
1535325 | no
12342   | yes
23252   | yes
434574  | no
1256532 | yes
```

of course I can write this and get the rows i have, but how can I determine if the row doesn't exist and get the output above:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Number]
  FROM [Contracts]
  where [Number] in 
  ('12342', '23252', '1256532')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put values into temporary table or a table variable and do `left join`:

```
declare @d table (Number varchar(10))
insert into @d values  ('12342'), ('23252'), ('1256532'), ('xxxx') -- last one is not in Contracts

SELECT c.[Id], c.[Number], case when d.Number is NULL then 'no' else 'yes' end [This Number from C is in D also]
FROM [Contracts] c
    left join @d d on d.Number = c.Number
```

for "opposite" use `right join`

```
SELECT c.[Id], d.[Number], case when c.Number is NULL then 'no' else 'yes' end [This Number from D is in C also]
FROM [Contracts] c
    right join @d d on d.Number = c.Number
```

Comment: thanks, but really i must stand from @d table, in other words if @d table has rows that are absent in [Number] I must display No. I changed script by your analogy but it doesnt work